# Adding a static header before the Listview in Nativescript

Tags: nativescript

I would like to implement a static content in my Page to show some values just before showing the RadListView provided by Telerik. This is my code example:

```
<lv:RadListView items="{{ dataItems }}" row="1" selectionBehavior="Press" itemSelected="onItemSelected">
    <lv:RadListView.listViewLayout>
        <lv:ListViewLinearLayout scrollDirection="Vertical"/>
    </lv:RadListView.listViewLayout>
    <lv:RadListView.itemTemplate>
        <StackLayout orientation="vertical">
            <Label fontSize="20" text="{{ itemName }}"/>
            <Label fontSize="14" text="{{ itemDescription }}"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </lv:RadListView.itemTemplate>
</lv:RadListView>
```

I am trying to add a Label just before the RadListView like this:

```
<StackLayout>
    <Label text="Listview Header!!!" />
</StackLayout>
```

I am trying to make the Label non-scrollable.

Once I change my code, nothing shows up in the page, any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need one main layout for this route/page. There can only be one child to the page (I know there's no page in NativeScript angular) but try adding a stack then placing what you have inside that one stack and it shouldn't work.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I did not explain myself correctly, I am trying to set a non-scrollable area just before the listview, so if you are scrolling items vertically, you can still see the area. Did I explain myself correctly? Thanks!

Comment: This is what @BradMartin wrote/said but as code/xml file content

So Label outside of RadListView should be visible always and RadListView will scroll

<StackLayout>
    <Label text="Listview Header!!!" />
    <lv:RadListView items="{{ dataItems }}" row="1" selectionBehavior="Press" itemSelected="onItemSelected">
      <!-- and other parts of your RadListView too long to put your whole code inside comment -->
    </lv:RadListView>
</StackLayout>